# how i call private block method without create object outside in ext Js?

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.define('App.View.ClassDemo', {
    privates: {
        runFactory: function () {
            this.factory('paresh');
        }
    },

    factory: function (brand) {
        alert(brand);
    }

});
```

this class contain privates block and its contain runFactory method how i call this method without creating object outside

Comment: have you try this.self?

Comment: Use `statics` since you want call mehtod without class instance?

Answer (score 0):

With ExtJS you can do something like this:

```
Ext.define('Computer', {
     statics: {
         factory: function(brand) {
             // 'this' in static methods refer to the class itself
             return new this(brand);
         }
     },

     constructor: function() { ... }
});

var dellComputer = Computer.factory('Dell');
```

The "factory" method is static and can be used without a Computer instance.